# Cannot find either column "databasename" or the user-defined function or aggregate "databasename.dbo.GetAliasesByACC", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAliasesByACC]
(
    @AccID int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @output varchar(max)
    select @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + Docnum
    from OPOR
    where TransID = @AccID 
    return @output
END
```

am Creating this function and call to UDF Field in SAP B1 AR invoice,

```
Declare @Var as nvarchar(max) 
set @Var= [databasename].[dbo].GetAliasesByACC(value) 
select @Var
```

Like this i have to call UDF field into this FMS query but showing some error  please check it.

> Error: 1). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot find either column "databasename" 
>   or the user-defined function or aggregate "databasename.dbo.GetAliasesByACC", or the name is ambiguous.

2). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL

Please solve this anone

Answer (score 0):

`databasename` it must be your database name.

Calling function in sql is like...

```
 Declare @Var as nvarchar(max) 
 set @Var= (Select  [databasename].[dbo].GetAliasesByACC(value) as OutVal)
 select @Var
```

Comment: I Will try this again showing some error please check it.   Error:1). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

2). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement 'User Display Cat.' (CUDC) (s) 
    could not be prepared.